# Large Dropdown Lookup with Autocomplete

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, dropdown, list-view-threshold

Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Requirement is a drop-down field in a SharePoint Online list that references a customer table in SharePoint Online. Of course, the customer table is well over the view limit threshold.

The format of the table is simple:

- Number  / Name
- A00800 ABC LABS INC
- A01000   ABSOLUTE INC
- A01001   ABB TREATMENT SOLUTIONS

The use-case: In a separate list, a user starts typing the Customer Number in a field, and if the Customer Number is in the Customer Table, it offers an autocomplete. Pressing TAB accepts the autocomplete, and the actual customer name is added to a separate field.

As you can see, the first initial of the Customer Number corresponds to the Customer Name. I don’t expect to have more than 1,000+/- customers beginning with the same letter/number – if that helps.

Anyone know of a way to handle this? I feel like I’m constantly hitting my head on the view threshold ceiling. Thinking there's no way to handle this out of the box and that a scripty solution may be needed.

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: Since I didn't get any responses, I don't really know if this is impossible or not. Seems like it shouldn't be impossible. No one knows?